# phpmyadmin no database password and name

Tags: phpmyadmin

When running

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

It completely installs, but I don't get to choose a username and password. When logging in with username: "root" and no password, I get the feedback

```
Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)
```

What should I do?

Comment: It expects the username and password you chose when installing MySQL.

Comment: I never got a prompt to choose a password or username while installing mysql